# Is there a way to apply the default css properties to an element with jquery that were defined in a css file?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to dynamically place content based on screen resolution. If the resolution is below 800px in width I want to adjust the elements as necessary but when the window is resized above 800px in width I want the css styles that are already defined in by external css file to be applied to the elements again. I can go through and change everything back again manually but it seems redundant. Is there an object oriented css trick or jquery function that I could use to do this?

Example

```
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        if(this.resizeTO) 
            clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
        this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() 
        {
            if(window.innerWidth < 800)
            {
                $("#usernameDisplay").css({top: "50px", right:"50%", "margin-right": "-" + $("#usernameDisplay").width()/2 + "px", "padding-top":"0px"});   
                $("#headerBack").css("height", "95px");
                $("#userMenuContainer").css({top: "95px", right:"50%", "margin-right": "-" + $("#userMenuContainer").width()/2 + "px"});
            }
            else
            {
                $("#usernameDisplay").css({top: "0px", right:"0", "margin-right": "0", "padding-top":"10px"});  
                $("#headerBack").css("height", "55px");
                $("#userMenuContainer").css({top: "110px", right:"0", "margin-right": "0"});
            }
        }, 200);
    });
```

Comment: So use `.addClass()` and get rid of `style` attribute

Comment: @Mr.Alien: That works well for applying static either/or values, less so for values you *are* calculating on-the-fly (`$("#usernameDisplay").width()/2 + "px"` for instance).

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. I'm asking to reapply previously defined css. Not replace it.

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty: You're asking how to remove inline styles (so the CSS rules take over). That question asks how to remove inline styles (and has ready answers). Or are we misunderstanding?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh I see, learning bee here :)

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I had no idea that applying css with jquery made them inline. I assumed that it went by specificity and changed the most specific value. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CSS rules apply a style, say:

```
.foo {
    left: 20px;
}
```

And you have an element that applies to:

```
<div class="foo">...</div>
```

If you then set the style value on the element itself, it overrides the CSS rule:

```
$(".foo").css("left", "30px"); // Or whatever
```

Note that it *overrides* it, it doesn't overwrite it.

If you then *remove* that style value from the element itself:

```
$(".foo").css("left", "");
```

...the CSS rule applies again and (in this case) the `left` property goes back to being 20px.

If you want to remove **all** inline styles you've applied to the element, you can do that by clearing the `style` attribute:

```
$("#usernameDisplay").attr("style", "");
```